# Select and Delete elements from bootstrap list

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap list which looks really nice.  However, I want to be able to select and delete elements from the list using a delete button at the bottom. I've been trying to include checkboxes in the list elements but without much success, they either dont show up at all or are underneath the list items which looks dreadful. Here's my code-

```
<ul id = "list" class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
    Group
  </a>
  <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="list-group-item">Maths</a> <input type = "checkbox">
  <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="list-group-item">History</a> <input type = "checkbox">
  <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="list-group-item">Chemistry</a> <input type = "checkbox">

</ul>
```

I've tried setting the float of the checkboxes to left but that had no effect. Ideally I'd rather have the checkboxes along the right hand side but this seems to break the link. Can anyone tell me how I can do this, or suggest a better way of selecting and deleting the list items? Newbie so excuse my lack of knowledge if this is an obvious question.

Comment: Can you put it on jsfiddle.net please ? More easy for us to help you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm I ended up putting it into a table. Probably was a very obvious question but here's my solution anyway-

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
<ul id = "list" class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
    Group </a>
  </td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type = "checkbox"></td>
  <td><a href="#" onclick="myFunction()" class="list-group-item">Maths</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type = "checkbox"></td>
  <td><a href="#" onclick="myFunction()" class="list-group-item">History</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type = "checkbox"></td>
  <td><a href="#" onclick="myFunction()" class="list-group-item">Chemistry</a></td>
  </tr>
</ul>
</table>
```